# CI - Public Variable for all pages?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wish to display a variable that is stored in a session at the top of each page throughout my website. At the minute, on every single page, in the controller `index()` I have;

`$data['credits'] = $this->session->userdata('credits');`

I havve created a seperate view for the navigation bar (where the variable will be displayed). I have called it `vNav.php`. In `vNav.php` I then do `echo $credits`.

For every new view, I have to include the `vNav.php`, but that also means in the other view's controllers, I have to set the `$data['credits']` variable in the `index()` function.

Is there a way in CI to do this automatically for me? So I don't have to have the same line of code in all my controllers?

Thanks

Comment: You could just get the session data in the view itself instead of passing it through $data

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's a better design for your views.

First, create a folder called include/, in this folder create a header.php, footer.php, template.php.

header.php

```
<html>
<head>JS - CSS - META</head>
<body>

<div>COMMON MESSAGE</div>
```

footer.php

```
<footer>FOOTER GOES HERE</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

template.php

```
$this->load->view('include/header.php');
$this->load->view($main_page);
$this->load->view('include/footer.php');
```

any controller:

```
$data['main_page'] = "hello_world"; // view/hello_world.php
$this->load->view('include/template',$data);
```

So in that way, you can create a common section that will be displayed on all pages by adding it to the header or the footer. If you want, you can also create another file in the include folder and then include it in the template so that it will be loaded automatically every where by only modified one file